# Windows 11 reduces apps CPU load when showing desktop

Tags: taskbar, cpu-usage, windows-11

I have a Windows 11 Pro Workstation on a MSI motherboard with an I9 chip on it. The workstation should do heavy CPU work during hours / days. I monitor energy consumption.

Everything is working fine while the apps are in the FOREGROUND and the window is visible (high CPU load and calculation speed is high). when I minimize the app to taskbar, CPU load drops and app calculation speed is droping to 20%.

I already set Performance Options (System -> About -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Processor scheduling) to Background Services

I need to have the apps at 100% load, even when logged off or minimized to taskbar. windows 7 and 10 is working fine there. Where is the difference to win 11?

Can this changed by settings?

Comment: Suffering same problem but on win10, priority of non-foreground apps does not appear to change.

Answer (score 1):

A user app that is is not frontmost isn't a 'Background Service', it's just a backgrounded app. Any sensible OS will de-prioritise a backgrounded app to give the priority to what the user normally wants - better performance for their current foreground app.

You can re-prioritise any app/process from the Task Manager, though this is a temporary measure.

[image]

See [Raymond.cc - 6 Tools to Permanently Set Process Priority in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/permanently-set-process-priority-in-windows-task-manager-with-prio/) for methods to change tis permanently.

Before running off to do that, though, set your overall pref back to prioritise Programs & see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I tried that, however the app still throttles down when minimized (from 100% to 30%). no other app is consuming CPU.  I tried with Realtime and High. Prior to this, I set the priority to Programs and restarted the PC.